# How to create a SCNNode from a .usdz?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, scnnode, usdz

I have downloaded the .usdz models provided by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/arkit/gallery/

But now, I want to create a SCNNode with one of these models, so I am doing this to obtain the node:

```
guard let urlPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "retrotv", withExtension: "usdz") else {
    return
}
let mdlAsset = MDLAsset(url: urlPath)
let modelRootNode = SCNScene(mdlAsset: mdlAsset).rootNode
```

Then I add it to the scene and the result is this:

[image]

Why does it have no textures?

I have the downloaded .usdz files into a folder in my project directory as you can see:

[image]

Comment: **Dude you simply forgot `.loadTextures()` that's all it is!**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The correct way to add the .USDZ object is actually creating the scene with the file's URL:

```
 let scene = try! SCNScene(url: usdzURL, options: [.checkConsistency: true])
```

Or even creating via Reference Node:

```
 let referenceNode = SCNReferenceNode(url: usdzURL)
 referenceNode.load()
```

Comment: Could I update the current scene with USD without create a new scene?

Comment: This older answer really isn't correct; you CAN load a file as "a whole scene" but there are very few or no situations where you would do that. It's easy and normal to load a file as a node, which is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to load a usdz into an ARKit scene.

It's important to have the these imports

```
import ARKit
import SceneKit
import SceneKit.ModelIO
```

Load the usdz via a URL.

```
guard let urlPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "retrotv", withExtension: "usdz") else {
    return
}
let mdlAsset = MDLAsset(url: urlPath)
// you can load the textures on an MDAsset so it's not white
mdlAsset.loadTextures()
```

Wrap it in a node.

```
let asset = mdlAsset.object(at: 0) // extract first object
let assetNode = SCNNode(mdlObject: asset)
```

You can now attach this node in ARKit. You would need to scale and orientate the object to where you want it in the real world, but that code depends on what you are trying to do, so I've left that out.

Comment: This is the only really correct answer here. The secret sauce is `object#at`.  Just a note, this works perfectly for scene kit (as well as AR, as mentioned in this answer).

Answer (score 0):

### The literal answer is that the OP forgot to load the textures.

It's easy to do,

```
asset.loadTextures()
```

### For 2023. It's very easy to make your .usdz a node.

The secret to understanding, is that a .usdz file contains (in theory) ***one or more*** different items or characters.

### The secret is to take the "first" (only) character in the file.

Almost always, a usdz file just has the one object. So you simply have the take the "first" (almost always only) object.

```
var fireDragon: SCNNode!

func loadDragonModel() {
  let p = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Amy1", withExtension: "usdz")!
  let ass = MDLAsset(url: p)
  ass.loadTextures()
  fireDragon = SCNNode(mdlObject: ass.object(at: 0))
}
```

That's it. And then,

```
  // .. some node of yours .. .addChildNode(fireDragon)
  // for example
  castleWall.addChildNode(fireDragon)
```

### This is for SceneKit and also ARKit.

All of this applies in SceneKit and ARKit. It works perfectly on tvOS, iOS, pad, phone, mac etc.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to access the Internal USDZ Node

```
func usdzNodeFrom(file: String, exten: String, internal_node: String) -> SCNNode? {
    let rootNode = SCNNode()
    let scale = 1

    guard let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: file, withExtension: exten) else {
        fatalError()
    }
    
    let scene = try! SCNScene(url: fileUrl, options: [.checkConsistency: true])
    let node = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: internal_node, recursively: true)!
    node.name = internal_node
    let height = node.boundingBox.max.y - node.boundingBox.min.y
    node.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
    tNode.scale = SCNVector3(scale, scale, scale)
    rootNode.addChildNode(tNode)
    return rootNode
}
```

Further texture not displaying is different Issue, could be addressed by adding lightning to environment.

Comment: why do you have tNode? And what is the internal_node name?

Comment: this appears to be an unrelated copy/paste, pls tap delete